# Implementing cryptography in Arangodb

Tags: cryptography, arangodb

Are there best practices in implementing encryption in Arangodb?

I am aware of that there is a crypto module here

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/javascript-api/crypto/

but I am unsure about implementation details.

I have to build a database with sensible data. The goal would be to store this data already encrypted in the cloud, so even the cloudprovider would not be able to read its contents.

But I am not sure, if this is posssible at all, like how would I query data, when it is encrypted?

On the other hand, I would not need to encrypt all data, it would be great already, if I could separate, which data belongs to which person/customer/user in the database.

Alls ideas, suggestions and hints on this are welcome, thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

Belated answer here, but basically any data at rest (or being stored in your database) should be encrypted. (data in motion should be encrypted as well, but that's another topic.) Encryption can be decrypted. In contrast, hashing is an irreversible process. Passwords should be stored salted and hashed, then when the user sends their password in you hash it with the same salt and compare. You can also pepper it if needed. But other sensitive data that you need to access again could not be hashed only encrypted.

It's a biiiiig topic, a little too big for a question here on SO I think, but below is a video that may be helpful. But I encourage you to do more research into SSL, Encryption, Shared Secrets, Public/Private Key Encryption, Hashing/Salting/Peppering.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q